# website keeps redirecting to HTTP

Tags: .htaccess, http, magento, ssl, https

i have just installed my SSL wich i have bought on transip.nl

When i take a look at the website which i have installed for it looks like its not going well.

i have checked : `https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-checker.html#hostname=sloffenenpantoffels.nl`

Looks fine but its not. there is no safe logo and he is still telling its an unscure connection.

When i check the URL its HTTP and not HTTPS.

Webshops is build in a magento multistore.

I have made own domain and selected his own IP for the SSL. I pointed the root folder to the folder from the main domain of the multistore.

In my htaccess file there is a rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)sloffenenpantoffels.nl

RewriteRule ^ - [E=MAGE_RUN_CODE:ditwiljehebben]
```

I hope that anyone can help me out here.

Answer (score 1):

To force SSL just use the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R,L]
```